# How to fake HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in RSpec controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, http-accept-language

I recently added some new code to a `before_action` in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = (session[:locale] || params[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header).to_s.downcase.presence || I18n.default_locale
  end

  private

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end

end
```

The problem is that the `extract_locale_from_accept_language_header` function disrupts all my controller specs (i.e. they all fail now). It seems that RSpec can't detect any `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

Is there a way to fake this behaviour for all my controller specs?

The following *does* work but is a bit ugly since I would have to add the line `request.env...` to all my controller tests. And I have many of them.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en" # ugly
  end

  ...

end
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in in your spec_helper:

```
config.before :each, type: :controller do
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en"
end
```

Try this for both controller and feature specs:

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
  if [:controller, :feature].include?(example.metadata[:type])
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en" # ugly
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This fixes all my controller specs. How about the feature specs, though? They still fail...

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'metadata' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007fb04ff38728>`

Comment: maybe a version issue, try to copy paste the first before each with `type` to check if that works

Comment: OK, I just tried `config.before :each, :type => :feature` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Done. But the `:type => :feature` spec still throws an error: `NameError:
       undefined local variable or method 'request' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007ff81cee0608>`

Comment: yep, unfortunately few webdrivers let you set the headers, look at the capybara page, there is an example for rack, for selenium, it seems there is a workaround: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/